# App not closing MySql connection properly

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm having a serious issue with my app. It builds a lot of MySql connections and then it's causing a crash.

I build every method like that:

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(
        local_connection_string
        ); //this is global variable.

    protected void sample()
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand(
                "here some mysql command"
                , connect);
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Dispose();
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
```

For some reason it's not closing any of these connections and when I keep refreshing it builds connections on the server, once limit is hit app is crashing. All connections are closed when app is shut down.

Comment: For one, why are you first Disposing then Closing ? On my SQLs i don't even bother Disposing. Simply .Close() does the trick perfectly fine.

Comment: You need to close first before disposing the connection...

Comment: As side note, you are currently catching and ignoring every exception: handle your catch in some way (which can be a simple `throw;`, if you want to pass the exception to the caller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnetion(local_connection_string)
{
    conn.open();
    MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand(
                "here some mysql command"
                , connect);
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

using(resource){}: right way for IDisposable resource usage
probably need to add: Application.ApplicationExit  event with MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools()

Comment: doesn't work, still building all connections on the server

Comment: at first it didn't work, but i've had other methods in my code. This works spot on!

Answer (score 1):

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL counter part uses Connection pooling and does not close when you call close instead it puts it in the connection pool!

Make sure you First Close then Dispose the Reader, Command, and Connection object!

You can use ConnectionString Parameter `"Pooling=false"` or the static methods `MySqlConnection.ClearPool(connection)` and `MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`

and `Using` keyword is the right way to go with this kind of Scenario.

Comment: setting Pooling to false does work, but is it me or it's a bit slower?

Comment: I am not sure is it slow! but you were okay. :) Happy Coding

Comment: yes, it is slower: without pooling your code will have to connect to db every time you create a new connection. With pooling, underlaying connection will actually stay alive even after you close it, and will be recycled if needed. If you don't have particular requirement, you should not disable pooling: everything will work ok as long as you properly close every `MySqlConnection` you use (`using` is your friend here)

Answer (score 0):

Just close first the connection , before calling the dispose...

```
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
            connect.Dispose();
        }
```